# What do we learn from quantizing the relativistic point particle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-gravity, quantization, point-particles

In many textbooks on string theory, some time is spend on quantizing  the relativistic point particle as a warming-up for quantizing the Nambu-Goto action for relativistic strings.

However, I have not found a clear explanation of why the theory of the quantum relativistic point particle is insufficient. What does this quantum theory tell us, and why is the upgrade to strings needed?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/716707/2451

Comment: If you cannot effectively quantize a relativistic point particle then you have no hope of quantizing a *world sheet*. In some sense quantizing point particles is as fundamental to string theory as point mechanics is to continuum mechanics.

Comment: some worldline aspects of the distinction between particles and strings, and why the former is not unique, is explained in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269390907925